# Python Dictionaries Print

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this dictionary but I'm not able to print it, could anyone tell me if there is an error?

```
groseries = {
    'fruits':[{
        'apples':['7'],
        'bananas':['4'],
        'lemmons':['7']
    }],
    'vegestables':[{
        'tomatoes':['3'], 
        'carrots':['9'], 
        'onions':['6']
    }],
    'cereals':[{
        'wheat':['11'],
        'granola':['7'],
        'kornflakes':['9']
    }]
}

print (groseries['cereals'][2])
```

Comment: You do understand that `groseries['cereals']` only has one element, right?

Comment: As @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams put it, `groseries['cereals']` yields a dictionary, not a list, so you have to use keys (like the `wheat`) instead of a numeric index.

Comment: @Arminius: No, there's a list. Look at the brackets on the `'cereals':[` line.

Comment: you spelled `groceries` wrong

Comment: @user2357112 of course, you are right. Lack of caffeine...:-)

Comment: @charitoo Please do not change variable names in someone's code. Typos in the question itself are fair game, but typos in the code could affect how the code works, and will be directly referenced by people attempting to respond. As it is, the answers here are now responding to different versions of this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you meant to format your code like this?:

```
groceries = {
    'fruits': {
        'apples':7,
        'bananas':4,
        'lemons':7
    },
    'vegetables': {
        'tomatoes':3,
        'carrots':9,
        'onions':6
    },
    'cereals': {
        'wheat':11,
        'granola':7,
        'cornflakes':9
    }
}
```

So then you can print how many apples you have like this:

```
print (groceries['fruits']['apples'])
```

or for cornflakes:

```
print (groceries['cereals']['cornflakes'])
```

On a trivial note, shouldn't tomatoes be in fruit? :P

Answer (score 1):

`groseries['cereals']` has only one element. So using index `2` for it throws the `IndexError` exception.

Thus the right usage is with the index `0` and the key 'kornflakes':

```
print(groseries['cereals'][0]['kornflakes'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `groseries['cereals'][0]['kornflakes']`.

It's a list of dictionaries (containing only one dictionary) inside `groseries['cereals']`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `groseries` dictionary to

```
groseries = {
    'fruits': {
        'apples': 7,
        'bananas': 4,
        'lemmons': 7
     },
     'vegestables': {
         'tomatoes': 3, 
         'carrots': 9, 
         'onions': 6
     },
     'cereals': {
         'wheat': 11,
         'granola': 7,
         'kornflakes': 9
     }
}
```

(no `lists` - as all your `lists` have just `1` item - no numbers in apostrophes, [PEP 8 Style Guide's](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) formatting) - and your life will be much easier.

And yes, then you may print the number (or the price?) of your favorite `kornflakes` cereal as simple as

```
print(groseries['cereals']['kornflakes'])
```

Comment: Thanks you very much MarianD, :D it finally work

Comment: You're welcome. Pleas consider upvote my answer if it was useful for you.